# constant URL for docker compose app deployed to AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, amazon-ecs

Is there some easy way that I am missing to get an unchanging, accessible to the internet URL for something I deploy to ECS with `docker compose up`?

I've written a small web app using flask and Nginx, put the flask and nginx portions into Docker containers, and deployed the thing to AWS ECS using [this workflow](https://www.docker.com/blog/docker-compose-from-local-to-amazon-ecs/), which boils down to:

```
docker context use myecscontext
docker compose up
```

This deploys the whole thing using AWS Fargate and makes it accessible from the internet at timot-LoadB-xyzxyzxyzxyzx-xyzxyzxyz.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com.  So far so good.

Now I'd like to make my-fancy-domain.com, registered with a non-AWS registrar, point to my web app.  I know I can edit the DNS entry at my registrar to do this; here's the catch: that URL with all the xyzs changes every time I `docker compose up` after making changes to my web app.  Must I really monkey around in my registrar's DNS settings every time I update something?

I had imagined I would simply slap an elastic IP on my new Fargate cluster when I'm satisfied that I want to replace the current live version with an update.  I see now that I can't easily associate an elastic IP with the load balancer that Fargate sets up.  And I would just as soon not move my-fancy-domain.com to Route53 simply to accomplish this.

Comment: Great question. [How can I use a static or Elastic IP address for an Amazon ECS task on Fargate?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ecs-fargate-static-elastic-ip-address/)

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary, thanks for the suggestion.  That and similar instructions elsewhere are actually what I meant when I said "can't *easily* associate an elastic IP".  21 steps, and I'm not even sure it's relevant because I wound up with an "application load balancer", not the "network load balancer" the link refers to.  These, and the AWS details of those instructions, are what I am hoping to abstract away.  I'd like to go from "container stack runs on my dev box" to "container stack runs at AWS" without needing to get that far into the weeds of networking on the AWS side.

Comment: I tried, unsuccessfully, to use the above instructions.  I created a Network Load Balancer, etc.  Step 18 opens into a whole bunch of configuration options that the resolution does not describe.  I made best guesses.  At the end I associated an elastic IP with the load balancer and pointed my DNS records there.  Still got a "site not found" after waiting a while for DNS to propagate.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who finds this in the future: what ended up working in the end was to move the DNS records for my site from my domain registrar to AWS Route53.

Once I did that the AWS Route53 console makes it straightforward to add an [alias record](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-choosing-alias-non-alias.html) pointing to the Application Load Balancer that the docker-compose/ECS integration set up.  Those alias records are "a Route 53–specific extension to DNS".

I did not want to move DNS records to Route53, but it did solve the problem.

Comment: How do you handle cases where the application load balancer is deleted due to running `docker compose down`? Although this question works if you plan to never shut off your cluster, it sounds like you are dependent on the ALB always being live.

Comment: @thank_you, the short answer is I didn't.  This was for a small, low-traffic demo site.  I was interested in this pipeline from an ease-of-use point of view but when I eventually got it working the (dollars and cents) cost of AWS Fargate was too great.  Because the traffic was low I didn't need to the load balancer, etc., so I scrapped Fargate, spun up an EC2 machine, and run docker compose up/down manually.  Sorry I can't be more helpful.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the response. Will consider what you said in my own problem/solution.